# Double byte filenames get corrupted if 'Download as zip' in Java

Tags: java, encoding

While downloading a folder from the remote path, file name gets junk characters.

eg:

```
remote path: "//10.7.456.78/abc/私はライオン"

local path: "C:\Users\test32\Desktop"

'私はライオン' folder contains 2 txt files 

1. はライ.txt  
2. ライ.txt
```

but after downloading the folder as Zip the file name contains junk characters like `½T½ñ.txt`.

Code Snippet :

```
if(isZip)  {
    int lastIndex = remotePath.lastIndexOf('/');
    filename = remotePath.substring(remotePath.lastIndexOf('/', lastIndex - 1) + 1, lastIndex);
    filename = filename.concat(".zip");
}
File file = new File(localPath + "/" + filename);

if (file.exists())
    return RES_FILE_EXISTS;
else if (!file.createNewFile())
    return -1;

InputStream reader = urlCon.getInputStream();
FileOutputStream writer = new FileOutputStream(file);

// Process body
int count;
long bytesSent = 0;
byte[] inarray = new byte[65534];

long fileSize = ((HttpsURLConnection) urlCon).getContentLength();

/* Initialize data transfer statistics */
long timeStart = System.currentTimeMillis();

while (bytesSent < fileSize && ((count = reader.read(inarray)) > 0) && run)  {
     writer.write(inarray, 0, count);
     bytesSent += count;
}

reader.close();
writer.flush();
writer.close();
```

If I download the folder without zip then the file name won't get corrupted.

it will be good if someone can help me in this issue.

Comment: thats probably do to encoding.

Comment: @Artur: Aside from the fact that this looks more like Japanese than Chinese, this question is less about languages and more about figuring out encoding problems.

Comment: I gave it as an example and also we use very few localized languages.

Comment: You say "if I download the folder as a ZIP". Which product do you use to create the ZIP file? Perhaps this is a problem with the product and not your code.

Comment: show us how you put your files in the zip

Comment: If the file names INSIDE the zip file are wrong, it's a problem with generation, not downloading.

Comment: looks to me the same. that the problem with the way I generate!. Is there any other way for this ?

Comment: *Comment from [Baron.Zhao](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1621483/baron-zhao)*: You should check the encoding of your app container

Comment: @varuag We can't tell you *other* ways until you explain how you currently do it.

Comment: code snippet has everything.. are you looking for urlCon info?

Comment: we want to know how you create your zip file

Comment: I am downloading the folder from a remote path as a zip file into the local path on the flow.

Comment: i understand that, but how does the zip file get created, is it already there? you seem to have a folder with files, does that folder already contain the zip?

Comment: Nope folder i am downloading as zip by creating the filename.zip and writing into it.

Comment: how do you write into it?

Comment: Well, it was tried several times, but let’s try again to explain: you are showing us a piece of code which just *copies* data as is. And that piece of code seems to be fine. The problem is that the server which provides the source data and the tool which you use to open the downloaded file afterwards must agree on the character encoding for the zip entry names. You are focusing on the only part of this chain which has no influence on this. It’s very likely that if you download the file with a browser you get the same result.

Comment: You don't need to call createNewFile(), and you don't need to test the number of bytes read against the file size. Just loop until end of stream. And don't call stream variables 'reader' and 'writer': it only causes confusion, given that Reader and Writer are JDK classes.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the system character encoding of remote server and local system does not match, or does not comply with each other.

Another possibility is a flaw in the remotePath variable. The code snippet does not show any clue how remotePath variable is generated. You may check the remotePath variable whether it contains the correct characters.